# Can I change the speed of an image sequence?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, image

I'm using an image sequence in a material, it draws a series of incremental model outputs for a flooding on a landscape. However it's moving too fast for the rest of the flyover animation. It doesn't have to be completely smooth, so I'm hoping I can slow it down by say only using 1 frame of the image sequence for every 2 frames of the animation, or some other ratio. In other parts I would like to speed it up again. Is there a way to do this?

I can think of one way to hack it and that would be to write a python script which duplicates some interval of the image files and then changes the sequence numbers, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Image sequence frame only every nth scene frame?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2409/change-image-sequence-frame-only-every-nth-scene-frame)

Comment: gandalf3, yes it is somewhat of a duplicate, but I don't think the answer to your question was satisfactory. If I want to do that method on a 5000 frame animation it will take forever, my suggested hack would be quicker. Maybe there is some Python magic that could be applied in Blender?

Comment: To change the speed so you have 5,000 images played over 10,000 frames of blender animation, you should only need two keyframes - frame 1 is image 1 and frame 10,000 is image 5,000 - ensure vector handles are used in the graph editor for a smooth change. For python magic use a driver instead of keyframes and make a python expression calculate which image to use based on current frame number.

Comment: sambler, I don't quite follow, could you elaborate on this in an answer? Then I could mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible by using drivers:

1. Add an Empty object somewhere;
2. In its **Object** panel, choose one Transform channel (such as Z Scale), type in `#frame`, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm. It will add a quick driver for the empty, make the Z scale value the same as the current frame number (e.g. If the current frame is 6, then the scale value will be driven to 6 automatically).
3. In **Cycles Material** node editor, move the mouse cursor over the *Offset* in Image Texture node, hit <kbd>D</kbd> to add a driver.
4. Open **Graph Editor**, switch to **Driver** mode, keep that node selected and you'll see the driver added. Set a variable based on the Z scale property of that Empty object. Type the expression like this: `variable_name * speed_fac`.

For example, in the example below, I used the variable name as `var` by default, and use 3 as speed factor, which means to make it playing 3X speed up.

[image]

[image]

**NOTE:**

- It's recommended to control node-related drivers by object transform, which is the tricky part, due to the current dependency limit on nodes.
- If The warning message occurs (as below), click **Reload Trusted**.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using basically the same idea as the answer from Leung Cheung you can use keyframes to animate the offset property for the image texture.

Go to the first frame (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>), hover the offset property and press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe. Then navigate to the last frame and enter the new offset value (lower if you want to slow down the texture animation) and again insert a keyframe.

In the F-Curve editor you can then adapt the speed of your texture animation. Even speed ramps are possible that way.

Answer (score 6):

Add effect strip -> speed control, then just make your image sequence length to 2 times or what you want
[See it in the manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/effects.html#speed-control)

Comment: Welcome to the site :) You might also want to add that this has to be done separately in the VSE.

Comment: thanks, this worked out for me!

Comment: This is perfect, and while I'm sure the driver method works this is much more direct and single-purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is to select all events in your timeline and then resize the length.