# Compositor: movie file input doesn't work properly with Time Remapping

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, video

I've got a animation project where the final render of each frame uses a movie clip frame from an external .avi file as input in the Compositor, so I can merge the movie file and the Blender-rendered object.

Initially, my project was 24fps, but I decided to change it to 60fps using the time remapping functionality and I converted the external video file from 24fps to 60fps. However, Blender still uses the 'wrong' frames from the video file as input for each frame, it seems that it uses the frame from the timeline, and not the 'remapped' frame number.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It's really hard to guess at what might be going on. Screenshots of your VSE setup and Time Remapper settings would be super helpful.

Comment: I'm not using the VSE. I'm using the node editor and an 'add' node to merge the two together. As for my Time Remapper, here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/fO1VXjH.png

Comment: do you have any strips on the VSE? If so those take precedence over the compositor.  In the Post Porcessing section of the Properties window uncheck "Sequencer" https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZsDz.png

Comment: No, my VSE is completely empty. I still unchecked 'Sequencer', it made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: Time remaper only affects 3D rendered output. All input movies are treated as having discreet frames counted against the scene timeline. To modify Image/Movie input node you have to hack the frame count of the node. See this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15562/can-i-change-the-speed-of-an-image-sequence